# Twitter Bootstrap Button dropdown z-index layering issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, layer

I've been pounding and pounding on this.
I have a comment section on my site with an option to edit with a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown button, but I as you can see below, it's hidden by the following comments.

[image]

I know it's not an `overflow` issue, as you can see the bottom of it under the last comment. So it can only be `z-index` layering issue. But I put all the comments on `z-index: 4` and the dropdown on `z-index: 1000`, so I have no idea what to do!

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssL1yydx/29/

Comment: This seems to be your problem .animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
} Remove it

Comment: Thanks! That indeed is causing the issue. Didn't know that an animation cause cause issues on layering (or probable more rendering).

Comment: @Andrew Do you think it's the fill-mode or the whole animation?

Comment: Ok Fixed it with a custom instead of the animated.css library.

Comment: @Andrew If you mark it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing:

```
 .animated { -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; animation-duration: 1s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; animation-fill-mode: both; }
```

Answer (score 2):

*Just have to change/add this css property*

**Css**:

```
.post{
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none !important;
}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ssL1yydx/31/