# Absolute parent overlaps absolute child div with z-index:1000

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, z-index

I have main parent div `.objects-wrap` which is absolutely positioned and in that I have a `table`.

Now as the columns increase the horizontal scroll comes in the bottom to parent div `.objects-wrap`.

Now the issue is in my last `td` there is bootstrap drop down menu which gets hidden because of the horizontal scroll bar even if there is a `z-index:1000` applied to dropdown menu.

The horizontal scroll bar overlaps the dropdown menu
What do I do to show the dropdown menu over the scrollbar

[Click here to see the JSfiddle for your reference](https://jsfiddle.net/s7hj3v56/)

I hope this explains the scenario and thanks in advance :)

Comment: @HTMLcodeHACKER In the fiddle if you look at the last row and in that last td and you click on that, you will see the menu is hidden behind the scrollbar

Comment: Your issue is `overflow`, not `z-index`.

Comment: @isherwood ok, how do I proceed ahead now, any help ?

Comment: I think this is not possible , with overflow-y:hidden to the parent container you won't be able to see the dropdown becusae it's his child independently of the z-index and absolute.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381746/handle-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-clipped-issue-having-overflow-auto-on-containe

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `overflow-y` property here :

```
.objects-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/s7hj3v56/3/)

It will add a vertical scrollbar when you click on the right link, is it ok ?

**EDIT**

Or you can set a min-height property on it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/s7hj3v56/4/)

```
.objects-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If you wants to not have the vertical scrollbar, you can change the `overflow-y` property to `visible`.

However you will have the vertical scrollbar when you click on the right link.

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/s7hj3v56/5/)

Comment: I have had done the same thing earlier,but my requirement is to show it over the scrollbar and not create vertical one.But thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, i edited my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: You will be surpised I have even tried the min-height thing.It can work but is there a way to overlap it over the scrollbar.  :)

Comment: Oh ok ! Overlap it over the scrollbar, I don't think so. Only `fixed` elements can overlap the scrollbar

Comment: Yups,got it working.I changed the drop-down menu position to fixed.now have to calculate its positions.Thanks :)